# Deleted definition of 'simple_vector::simple_vector(int)'

Tags: c++, class, constructor, dynamic-arrays

I'm creating a simple vector class in C++ using dynamic arrays. The constructor with an `int` parameter must be deleted.

I have two errors:

- Deleted definition of `simple_vector::simple_vector(int)` from my cpp file.
- Previous declaration of `simple_vector::simple_vector(int)` from my hpp file.

What's going on? The name of my class is `simple_vector`. It can only contain `double` elements.

Honestly, I have no idea what to do.

Hpp file

```
simple_vector(const int a);
```

Cpp file

```
simple_vector::simple_vector(const int a) = delete;
```

Comment: Make your constructor explicit. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121162/what-does-the-explicit-keyword-mean

Comment: @RetiredNinja You get better error messages if deleted functions are not explicit ("No viable function" becomes "Use of deleted function" when trying to implicitly convert, which makes the intent that you can't construct from `int` more clear)

Comment: Unless you plan to write a deleted constructor for every possible type that could convert then explicit is still a good idea if you do not want implicit conversion. It doesn't have to be a one or the other thing.

Comment: As a point of information, C++ does not support dynamic arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't mark your constructor as `delete`'d on its *definition* in the `cpp` file, you need to mark it on its *declaration* in the `hpp` file instead.

In the `hpp` file, change this:

```
simple_vector(const int a);
```

To this:

```
simple_vector(const int) = delete;
```

And in the `cpp` file, remove this completely:

```
simple_vector::simple_vector(const int a) = delete;
```

Comment: After all, how would the compiler flag a use as an error if the `=delete` were hidden in another translation unit?